# Docker can't connect and pull an image from an existing repository

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I've racked my head on this for over 6 hours to no avail.

Whenever I run this code:

```
docker run --name mina -d \
-P 8302:8302 \
--restart=always \
--mount "type=bind,source=`pwd`/keys,dst=/users/gb/keys,readonly" \
--mount "type=bind,source=`pwd`/.coda-config,dst=/users/gb/.coda-config" \
--mount "type=bind,source=`pwd`/peers.txt,dst=/users/gb/peers.txt,readonly" \
-e CODA_PRIVKEY_PASS=PASSWORD \
gcr.io/o1labs-192920/coda-daemon-baked:0.4.2-245a3f7-zenith-7a89538 \
daemon \
-peer-list-file /users/gilbertbassey/peers.txt \
--block-producer-key /users/gb/keys/my-wallet \
--insecure-rest-server \
--file-log-level Debug \
--log-level Info \
```

I get this:

```
Unable to find image '8302:8302' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 8302, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

I know that the repository exists because other people have accessed it. I am running this code on my Mackbook terminal using Docker desktop.

For a bit more context: I am trying to connect to a blockchain network.

EDIT:

It turns out that I have been having this problem because of my password. It has a few special characters that docker is misinterpreting/deleting. Specifically, `!!` at the end of the password seems to be the issue. How can I write it in a way that docker doesn't misinterpret?

Comment: You have a `-P` option, with a capital "P"; that tells Docker to publish all exposed ports and doesn't take an argument, and in turn, that causes the next argument to be interpreted as the image name.  Do you mean `-p` with a lowercase "p"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you open the port with the wrong argument

```
Unable to find image '8302:8302' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 8302, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

Unable to locate image '8302: 8302' locally, says not found because there is no such image already

**[Try]**

```
docker run --name mina -d \
-p 8302:8302 \
--restart=always \
--mount "type=bind,source=`pwd`/keys,dst=/users/gb/keys,readonly" \
--mount "type=bind,source=`pwd`/.coda-config,dst=/users/gb/.coda-config" \
--mount "type=bind,source=`pwd`/peers.txt,dst=/users/gb/peers.txt,readonly" \
-e CODA_PRIVKEY_PASS=PASSWORD \
gcr.io/o1labs-192920/coda-daemon-baked:0.4.2-245a3f7-zenith-7a89538 \
daemon \
-peer-list-file /users/gilbertbassey/peers.txt \
--block-producer-key /users/gb/keys/my-wallet \
--insecure-rest-server \
--file-log-level Debug \
--log-level Info
```

> To open ports out you had to use -p instead of -P

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. The original code had -p but I changed it cos of the errors I was getting. But now I see that the problem was my password. For some reason, docker doesn't read it completely. `-e CODA_PRIVKEY_PASS=@sdsfaGH!! ` This has been the cause of all my errors. Now I need to figure out how to make the system read the password without messing with it. I notice that it keeps deleting the exclamation marks

Comment: You can send the password as a string. For example CODA_PRIVKEY_PASS="@sdsfaGH!!"

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to turn off hash expansion using `set +H` so that the program would read `!!` without expanding/executing it. Thanks a lot for the help, it's much appreciated.